# Angular Protractor update to 6.0.0 causes browser crashes

Tags: angular, jasmine, protractor, selenium-chromedriver, e2e-testing

I updated Protractor from v. 5.4.2 to v. 6.0.0 (to get i.a. `withContext` from Jasmine 3.0). Old code and everything works fine on my machine (Win 10), after small changes in code caused by upgrade. Unfortunately, when I'm trying to deploy that changes to K8S pod (Linux-based), then it's failing:

```
[10:05:22] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[10:05:22] E/launcher - Error: WebDriverError: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
    at Object.throwDecodedError (/app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:550:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (/app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:563:13)
    at Executor.execute (/app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:489:26)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
[10:05:22] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100
```

I have no idea, why it happens, both my machine and k8s should use Chrome and ChromeDriver v. 77. Of course, tests was running on old Protractor properly on both environments.

EDIT:

```
        'browserName': 'chrome',
        'moz:firefoxOptions': {
            'args': ['']
        },
        chromeOptions: {
            args: [
                "--disable-gpu",
                "--window-size=1366,768",
                "--no-sandbox",
                "--disable-dev-shm-usage",
                "--disable-infobars"
            ]
        }
    },
```

and additional: `configuration.capabilities.chromeOptions.args.push("--headless");` in case of Linux, etc.

For the test I moved `--headless` to base configuration and on Windows it don't run in headless, but when I change `chromeOptions` to `'goog:chromeOptions'` then it enters headless as expected. I tried it also on Ubuntu, but I get:

```
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/<project>/protractor.base.conf.js:136:46)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/<project>/protractor.dev.conf.js:1:22)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
```

Comment: try adding these parameters to your chrome instance `--headless` `--no-sandbox` `--disable-dev-shm-usage`, if helps I'll give the full answer what and why happens

Comment: We use:
`--disable-gpu`, `--size=1366x768`, `--sandbox`, `--disable-dev-shm-usage`,
`--disable-infobars` (all cases)
and `--headless` when used on Linux (or when set manually on Windows).
( `configuration.capabilities.chromeOptions.args.push("--headless");`

Comment: My experience with this problem was next. Essentially, browser doesn't start because there is no UI in Linux, so I should have used headless mode (which I didn't want) or install in docker image buffering app called `xvfb` and run the process in its mode, so it buffers the image visualization in the background. I hope it'll help you to narrow down your problem's cause

Comment: I updated question, maybe you'll find something now?